# Add Buttons to Scatterplot Map

Tags: python, plotly

I want to add circles around the clusters generated in this map of haunted place in New England. I'm very new to Plotly, can anyone help me out?

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# read the data set
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.github.khoury.northeastern.edu/acroak/5800_group_project/keegan/final_dataset.csv?token=GHSAT0AAAAAAAAANYCR2GW742FPYYVQI4UEZCP77IQ')

# create figure
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df,
                        lon = df['long'], 
                        lat = df['lat'],
                        hover_name = df['Place'],                        
                        zoom = 6,
                        width = 1200,
                        height = 900,
                        color = df['Centroid Index'],
                        size = [.5]*len(df),
                        size_max=10,
                        title = 'Kruskals Clusters and Creeps')



fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0, "t":50, "l":0, "b":10})

fig.show()
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Generate dataset
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x0 = np.random.normal(2, 0.4, 400)
y0 = np.random.normal(2, 0.4, 400)
x1 = np.random.normal(3, 0.6, 600)
y1 = np.random.normal(6, 0.4, 400)
x2 = np.random.normal(4, 0.2, 200)
y2 = np.random.normal(4, 0.4, 200)

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x0,
        y=y0,
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(color="DarkOrange")
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x1,
        y=y1,
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(color="Crimson")
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x2,
        y=y2,
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(color="RebeccaPurple")
    )
)

# Add buttons that add shapes
cluster0 = [dict(type="circle",
                            xref="x", yref="y",
                            x0=min(x0), y0=min(y0),
                            x1=max(x0), y1=max(y0),
                            line=dict(color="DarkOrange"))]
cluster1 = [dict(type="circle",
                            xref="x", yref="y",
                            x0=min(x1), y0=min(y1),
                            x1=max(x1), y1=max(y1),
                            line=dict(color="Crimson"))]
cluster2 = [dict(type="circle",
                            xref="x", yref="y",
                            x0=min(x2), y0=min(y2),
                            x1=max(x2), y1=max(y2),
                            line=dict(color="RebeccaPurple"))]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            buttons=[
                dict(label="None",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["shapes", []]),
                dict(label="Cluster 0",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["shapes", cluster0]),
                dict(label="Cluster 1",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["shapes", cluster1]),
                dict(label="Cluster 2",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["shapes", cluster2]),
                dict(label="All",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["shapes", cluster0 + cluster1 + cluster2])
            ],
        )
    ]
)

# Update remaining layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Highlight Clusters",
    showlegend=False,
)

fig.show()
```

I'm confused by how to make what is in the tutorial work with my data and can't find any clear documentation or explanation of how/why this works.

Comment: Is the link to the data reference in the question correct? I cannot retrieve the data.